# If $M \subset \mathcal{H}$ is closed then $M^{\bot \bot}=M$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is an Hilbert space and that $M \subset \mathcal{H}$ is closed.
I would like to prove that $M^{\bot \bot}=M$. I only know that $M \subset M^{\bot \bot}$.

How can I prove $M^{\bot \bot} \subset M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Hilbert space, with $M$ a closed subspace, $H=M+M^\perp$.
[Proof of $H=M+M^\perp$: Given any point $x\in H$, there is a closest point to it in $M$, call it $a$ and let $b:=x-a$. Pick $a'\in M$ and let $y:=(b-\langle a,b\rangle a)\perp a$ ($a$ unit), then $\|b\|^2=\|y\|^2+|\langle a,b\rangle|^2$ so $\|y\|\le\|b\|$ a contradiction unless $\langle a,b\rangle=0$.]

If $x\in M^{\perp\perp}$ then $x=a+b$ with $a\in M$, $b\in M^\perp$.

But then $$0=\langle x,b\rangle=\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle=\|b\|^2$$ so $b=0$ and $x=a\in M$.